# Multiply every item in list with every item in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists

```
listA = [2,3,4]
listB = [3,4,5]
```

I want to know if there is an easy way to multiply each item in the list with each item in the other list without using multiple for loops. Ultimately I should get the below answer

```
listC = [6,8,10,9,12,15,12,16,20]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are looking for itertools.product which does the cartesian product of iterables

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
import iterools
print([a * b for a, b in itertools.product(listA, listB)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

listA = [2, 3, 4]
listB = [3, 4, 5]
listC = [a * b for a, b in itertools.product(listA, listB)]
print(listC)
# [6, 8, 10, 9, 12, 15, 12, 16, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `List comprehension`

```
listA = [2,3,4]
listB = [3,4,5]
l = [i * j for i in listA for j in listB]
print(l)

#[6, 8, 10, 9, 12, 15, 12, 16, 20]
```

Comment: I know the typical answer will revolve around `itertools.product()` but I like this one as it avoids that import.

Answer (score 0):

Good solutions were already provided. Here is another one with `math.prod`:

```
from itertools import product
from math import prod
list(map(prod, product(listA, listB)))
# > [6, 8, 10, 9, 12, 15, 12, 16, 20]
```

In case you want to do it with any number of lists, you can use `math.prod` to reduce:

```
list_of_list = [[2,3], [3,4], [10, 12]]
from itertools import product
from math import prod
list(map(prod, product(*list_of_list)))
# > [60, 72, 80, 96, 90, 108, 120, 144]
```

Both `math` and `itertools` are python built-in modules.